# Get Range to set first element as setStart

Tags: javascript, range

How would I assign the setStart and setEnd range to the first element (could be text, an image, hyperlink...) in the document?

Comment: Try `document.body.childNodes[0]`.

Comment: Would it go something like `range.setStart(document.body.childNodes[0], 1);`  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean the first element within the body of the document, I'd suggest the following. It uses [`setStartBefore()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/range.setStartBefore) in case the element is one that cannot have children, such as `<img>` or `<br>`:

```
var range = document.createRange();
var firstElInBody = document.body.getElementsByTagName("*")[0];
if (firstElInBody) {
    range.setStartBefore(firstElInBody);
    range.collapse(true);
}
```

One final thing: in case you're not aware, IE < 9 does not support `Range`.

Comment: Thanks Tim. Worked beautifully!